# grep using pattern.file in multiple files and show only unmached string from pattern

Tags: bash

I would like to grep with using patternfile (contains like 16000+ values) to search in several xml. and i want to print into txt only those strings from pattern which are unmached

tried several methods like grep -oh , Fvf closest i could get is printing the whole matched xml into .txt

my pattern

> 000001
>   000002
>   000003
>   000004
>   000005
>   000006
>   etc

one of xml

> (xy)000001(xy)
>   (xy)000002(xy) 
>   (xy)000003(xy) 
>   (xy)000004(xy)

my desired result would be

> 000005
>   000006

Comment: This should be reasonably easy using Awk if I understand your requirement correctly.

Comment: You should show us some of the patterns you tried and maybe help you adjust them to get the desired result

Comment: so put another way, you want your list to work as an exclusion list? Processing XML with *nix line-based stream tools is a recipe for insanity. You're better off loading your XML into an XML aware DB and processing there with a simple `SELECT` statement. Good luck.

Comment: Btw `(xy)` does not remotely resemble XML, maybe you should include some more 'realistic' sample.

Answer (score 0):

You need to describe your format more exactly, if you want more exact answer. But in general:

- think twice before parsing XML with line oriented tools (same goes for JSON)
- your task can be split into two parts

  - getting the non-matching lines
  - filtering out the mess to keep only the IDs

Which leads to a pipeline of this shape:

```
grep -Fv -f patterns your.xml files.xml | 
  egrep -o "[0-9]{6}"
```

You can replace the `egrep` part according to your real data with something like `cut -c 5-11` ...

Comment: thanks for your response,
i'm using my patterns pattern.txt, i have multiple unique values, and i like to check through many xml, and i only need those which are not appeared in the search but in the pattern. when i used ur line it apparently cut out every 6 digit long value from the 'files.xml'.

Comment: My pipeline first searches the two `.xml` files for lines where there is no exact match for any line in file `patterns`, then it extracts all six digit numbers from such lines. Check if the first part does what you expect by piping to `head` or `less`. I cannot guarantee that your XML files even do have line breaks, they don't have to...

Comment: im starting to give up all i could do is:

`while read LINE; do if grep -q $LINE *.xml; then results=$(grep -Hni $LINE *.xml); echo [+] Found: $results; else echo [-] Not found: $LINE;fi;done < pattern.txt`

but it marks everything not found, even thoose values which are found

Comment: @nullpointer_ you need to improve the sample data in your question to get a better answer. I'm quite sure you don't want to  loop over your input file in a bash loop..;)

Comment: That was exactly what i wanted, cuz i had 100 xml with unique values in it and i wanted to check each one of in my patter in all of my xmls. But i gave up and did it with python. Anyway thanks for your help!!